# JavascriptExecutor doesn't work properly with Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I use `JavascriptExecutor` to input the text. My code snippet is as follows

```java
 private void inputWorkDescription(WebDriver driver, int rawNumber) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        if (!getWorkDescriptionFromSheets(rawNumber).isEmpty()) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAITING_PERIOD);
            WebElement workDescription = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
                    By.cssSelector("span.placeholder-decoration.ProseMirror-widget span")));
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", workDescription);          // ---WORKS
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='123456';", workDescription);   // --- DOESN'T WORK
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" 
+ getWorkDescriptionFromSheets(rawNumber) + "');", workDescription);   // --- DOESN'T WORK
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly. I just see that `click` command performed but no text input.
I tried different options for text input but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, couple of thoughts - Your css identifier is a span. Does it need to be an input? How else can it contain the value?... And, Have you tried using the normal selenium sendkeys? Javascript is normal a work around when sendkeys doesn't work as it's further away from being an actual user action.

Comment: Yes, it's text box and click is working. I tried to use standard sendKeys but received exception: element not interactable that is why I use JS.

Comment: Could you provide html code?

Comment: You were right. I used wrong identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wrong css identifier.

The answer on my question is on screenshot below

[image]